# I have a random element from the string[] animals selected and i want clues to equal the selected element. How do I get the clue to equal the element?

Tags: java

My arrays are in one class

```
 private final String[] words = { "reddit", "facebook", "java", "assignment",
            "game", "helloWorld", "weather", "religion", "internet", "face"};
    private final String[] animals = {"squirrel", "dog", "monkey", "panda", "rat",
            "kangaroo", "horse", "elephant", "fox", "cow"};
    public String password;
    private StringBuilder password Hidden;
    private String[] animals Clues = {"Lives in trees and has a long fluffy tail", "Human's best friend", "Were are ancestors", "Has a Kung Fu movie", "Lives in New york sewers ", "Can kick you", "Looks like a Zebra", "Biggest land mammal ", "The hound and the ___" , "Our milk comes from" };
    private String[] word Clues = {"Social new website", "What has your face and you can read it", "Coding language", "During this course, you've had", "ps4's have ", "first line of code we saw said", "its raining, what horrible __ ", "people have different", "uses code", "attached to our head"}; 
    private String clues;
```

how can i get the animals[] to equal clues?

```
//this is where i show the hint in the jpanel.
private void getWord(){

        JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField Intext = new JTextField();
        HintPanel.add(Intext);



        Hint.setText("Hint: " + clues);

        }
```

https://github.com/Lwilliams002/Hangman-game/blob/main/HangmanGame.java
Here is the repository to see the code

Comment: You’ll need to keep the index you used to select the word, and use the same index to select the clue

Comment: This is an excellent demonstration of why not to use _parallel arrays_ like that. Instead, you want a class `Puzzle` with properties `word` and `clue`, and you can make an array (or List) of that.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a suggestion, perhaps rethink the way you want to do this. Instead of using a bunch of arrays have specific Classes to handle instances of Animals, Words, and whatever else you might want. For example, if you have an animal named `Dog` then then there can be an instance of `Dog` which also has an instance of a String Array of **clues** for `Dog`.

The **Animals** class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Animals {

    private String animalName;
    private String[] animalClues;
    private static final List<Animals> animalInstances = new ArrayList<>();

    public Animals() {
        Animals.animalInstances.add((this));
    }

    public Animals(String animalName, String[] animalClues) {
        this.animalName = animalName;
        this.animalClues = animalClues;
        Animals.animalInstances.add((this));
    }

    public String getAnimalName() {
        return animalName;
    }

    public void setAnimalName(String animalName) {
        this.animalName = animalName;
    }

    public String[] getAnimalClues() {
        return animalClues;
    }

    public void setAnimalClues(String[] animalClues) {
        this.animalClues = animalClues;
    }

    public static List<Animals> getAnimalInstances() {
        return animalInstances;
    }
    
}
```

You could now have instances of a various number Animals and this could be created from file data. As an example, let's say we have the following animals data text file named `Animals.dat`:

```
# For specific animals and clues to those animals.

<Dog>
Mans best friend.
Likes to knaw on bones.
Has four legs.
Makes a great pet.
Likes to run around a park.
Likes to bark.
    
<Zebra>
Is black and White.
Has stripes.
Has four legs.
Has a unique pattern.
Part of the horse family.
Might see on a safari.
Start with the letter Z.

<Cat>
Has four legs.
Likes to sleep a lot.
Usually stays within the home.
A very common pet.
Likes to catch mice.
Sometimes known as a feline.
Rumored to have nine lives.

<Bear>
Is a mammal.
Has four legs.
Muppets Fozzie.
A Paddington.
Height and strength is very significant.
Has big paws and thick fur.
Hibernates in winter.
Can sometimes see one when camping.
```

You can create instances of `Animal` from the data in this file which is demonstrated in the provided runnable code below. The Console Application code I provide below permits the User to choose whether to guess an Animal or a Word. Which class is used depends upon what the User selects (Animal or Words). There is also scoring which takes place during the running of this application and the User can quit at any time.

Here is the code. The Animal class is already displayed above:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class CluesDemo {
    
    // Make Scanner object class global so that we can use it anywhere.
    private final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Started application this way to avoid 
        // the need for statics.
        new CluesDemo().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        String menuOption = "";
        String gameFile = "Animals.dat";
        while (menuOption.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Select what you want guess for in this game:");
            System.out.println("  1) Animals");
            System.out.println("  2) Words");
            System.out.println("  3) Quit");
            System.out.print("Your Choice: --> ");
            menuOption = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            if (!menuOption.matches("[1-3]")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid menu choice! Try again...");
                System.out.println();
                menuOption = "";
            }
        }
        /* switch/case is used in various locations so 
           that you can add more game file types if you
           like.        */
        switch (menuOption) {
            case "1":
                gameFile = "Animals.dat";
                break;
            case "2":
                gameFile = "Words.dat";
                break;
            case "3":
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing. Bye-Bye.");
                System.exit(0);
        }
        loadGameFile(gameFile, menuOption);
        
        System.out.println();
        switch (menuOption) {
            case "1":
                playAnimals();
                break;
            case "2":
                playWords();
                break;
        }
    }
    
    private void playAnimals() {
        List<Animals> gameTypeList = Animals.getAnimalInstances();
        int score = 0;              // Score sum
        /* The max possible score for the current question. 
           The value in this variable changes based on the 
           questions total number of clues minus the number 
           of clues used.         */
        int possibleMaxScore = 0;   
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("The computer has randomly selected an animal.");
            System.out.println("You are tasked to determine what that animal");
            System.out.println("is based on the random clues provided. Enter");
            System.out.println("'q' to quit at any time:");
            System.out.println();
            
            int randomAnimal = new Random().nextInt(gameTypeList.size() - 1);
            String answerAnimal = gameTypeList.get(randomAnimal).getAnimalName();
            List <Integer> cluesPlayed = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] clues = gameTypeList.get(randomAnimal).getAnimalClues();
            possibleMaxScore = clues.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < clues.length; i++) {
                int clueNum = 0;
                if (clues.length > 1) {
                    clueNum = new Random().nextInt(clues.length - 1);
                }
                if (cluesPlayed.contains(clueNum)) {
                    /* Clue was aleady played for this particular animal.
                       we don't want to see this clue again unless the
                       animal was randomly selected again.           */
                    if (cluesPlayed.size() == (clues.length -1)) {
                        /* If we've played all the clues and there still
                           is no correct answer then exit this loop and
                           question to start a new one.             */
                        break;
                    }
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                cluesPlayed.add(clueNum); // Add this clue to the cluesPlayed list.
                System.out.println("Clue #" + (i + 1) + ": " + clues[clueNum]);
                System.out.print("The animal is? --> ");
                String answer = userInput.nextLine().trim(); // Get User input.
                // Is quit desired?
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                    // Yes...so quit the application.
                    System.out.println("Thanks for playing. Bye-Bye.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                // Was the right animal supplied by User?
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answerAnimal)) {
                    // Yes...
                    System.out.println("==================================================");
                    System.out.println("Correct!! '" + answerAnimal.toUpperCase() 
                                     + "' is the animal we were thinking of!");
                    score += possibleMaxScore;
                    System.out.println("Current Score: " + score);
                    System.out.println("==================================================");
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    // No...
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Wrong!! A " + answer + " is NOT the animal "
                                     + "we were thinking of!");
                    possibleMaxScore--;
                    score--;
                    System.out.println("Current Score: " + score);
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void playWords() {
        List<Words> gameTypeList = Words.getWordInstances();
        int score = 0;              // Score sum
        /* The max possible score for the current question. 
           The value in this variable changes based on the 
           questions total number of clues minus the number 
           of clues used.         */
        int possibleMaxScore = 0;   
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("The computer has randomly selected a word.");
            System.out.println("You are tasked to determine what that word");
            System.out.println("is based on the random clues provided. Enter");
            System.out.println("'q' to quit at any time:");
            System.out.println();
            
            int randomWord = new Random().nextInt(gameTypeList.size() - 1);
            String answerWord = gameTypeList.get(randomWord).getWord();
            List <Integer> cluesPlayed = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] clues = gameTypeList.get(randomWord).getWordClues();
            for (int i = 0; i < clues.length; i++) {
                int clueNum = 0;
                if (clues.length > 1) {
                    clueNum = new Random().nextInt(clues.length - 1);
                }
                if (cluesPlayed.contains(clueNum)) {
                    /* Clue was aleady played for this particular word.
                       we don't want to see this clue again unless the
                       word was randomly selected again.            */
                    if (cluesPlayed.size() == (clues.length - 1)) {
                        /* If we've played all the clues and there still
                           is no correct answer then exit this loop and
                           question to start a new one.             */
                        break;
                    }
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                cluesPlayed.add(clueNum);
                System.out.println("Clue #" + (i + 1) + ": " + clues[clueNum]);
                System.out.print("The word is? --> ");
                String answer = userInput.nextLine().trim();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                    System.out.println("Thanks for playing. Bye-Bye.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answerWord)) {
                    System.out.println("==================================================");
                    System.out.println("Correct!! '" + answerWord.toUpperCase() 
                                     + "' is the word we were thinking of!");
                    score += possibleMaxScore;;
                    System.out.println("Current Score: " + score);
                    System.out.println("==================================================");
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Wrong!! " + answer.toUpperCase() + " is NOT the word "
                                     + "we were thinking of!");
                    possibleMaxScore--;
                    score--;
                    System.out.println("Current Score: " + score);
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void loadGameFile(String DataFilePath, String menuOption) {
        // Read in game data
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DataFilePath))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                if (line.isEmpty() || line.startsWith("#")) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (line.startsWith("<") && line.endsWith(">")) {
                    String tagName = line.substring(1, line.lastIndexOf(">"));
                    List<String> cluesList = new ArrayList<>();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        line = line.trim();
                        if (line.isEmpty()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        cluesList.add(line);
                    }
                    // Which class are we going to create instances of.
                    switch (menuOption) {
                        case "1": 
                            Animals tmp1 = new Animals(tagName, cluesList.toArray(new String[cluesList.size()]));
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            Words tmp2 = new Words(tagName, cluesList.toArray(new String[cluesList.size()]));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CluesDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CluesDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

The **Words** class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Words {
    
    private String word;
    private String[] wordClues;
    private static final List<Words> wordInstances = new ArrayList<>();

    
    public Words() {
        Words.wordInstances.add((this));
    }

    public Words(String word, String[] wordClues) {
        this.word = word;
        this.wordClues = wordClues;
        Words.wordInstances.add((this));
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String[] getWordClues() {
        return wordClues;
    }

    public void setWordClues(String[] wordClues) {
        this.wordClues = wordClues;
    }

    public static List<Words> getWordInstances() {
        return wordInstances;
    }
    
}
```

And a `Word.dat` file might look something like this:

```
# For specific Words and clues to those Words.

<Reddit>
A Relatively new social website.

<Facebook>
What has your face and you can read it.

<Java>
Coding language.
Over 3 billion devices use it.

<Assignment>
During this course, you've had an __.

<Game>
PS4's have this ...

<HelloWorld>
First program we learned put this on screen.
Well "Hi" back at ya.

<Weather>
It's raining, what horrible __.

<Religion>
People have different ...
One faith or another.

<Internet>
Uses code.
Has cookies.
You can buy it from the __.
Great place to get content.
www.

<Face>
It's attached to our head.
Has a bunch of features.
It contains two eyes, a nose, and a mouth.
Might have dimples.
Is sometimes dirty after a hard day.
```

In the above runnable, Animals (or Words) to be guessed are randomly selected. Displayed Clues are also randomly chosen for the specific Animal or Word to be guessed. Scoring points are based on the number of clues available for any specific Animal or Word. If an specific Animal has 6 clues then the User has the potential to get 6 points for a correct guess with the first clue. That potential is reduced by 1 for every clue presented for that particular animal.

This can obviously be done a lot better but it was **quick** and is only provided here as a mere example of another possible alternative to what you are trying to accomplish. Doing something like this also has the potential to be relatively scalable. And, text files can hold the data bulk of it which makes for easy editing, additions, and deletions rather than hard-coding it all.

Answer (score 0):

first check which array has the input string, then get the its index
get the element from respective clues array using that index

```
// converting array to list
        List<String> listOfWords = Arrays.asList(words);
        List<String> listOfAnimals = Arrays.asList(animals);
```

getting index of input string from arrays

```
        int indexInAnimals = listOfAnimals.indexOf(input);
        int indexInWords = listOfWords.indexOf(input);
```

get the clue from array using index

```
        if(listOfWords.contains(input)) {
            clue = wordClues[indexInWords];
        } else if (listOfAnimals.contains(input)) {
            clue = animalsClues[indexInAnimals];
        }
      //clue for the input
       System.out.println(clue);
```

Input: `panda`

Output:

```
Has a Kung Fu movie
```